# Cordova Android barcoding callbacks not working

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

Am trying to setup a barcoding app on Android and am stuck. The camera barcode function is iniatilized and am able to capture a barcode however nothing happens after that. The callbacks for success/fail don't seem to get called at all. Below is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="camera.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="childbrowser.js"></script>
 <script src="resources/js/barcoding.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 

</head>

<body class="home">
<div class="container">
        <div class="containerLogin">
                <header class="header"><img src="resources/images/logo.png" width="285" height="71" alt="Autopic" /></header>
        </div>
        <div class="containerMain">
                <h1>Welcome back <span id="name"></span></h1>
                <ul>
                        <li><span class="picture"></span><a href="" id="scan">Scan barcode</a></li>
                        <li><span class="picture"></span><a href="viewpics.html">View pictures</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <select id="searchtype" onchange="getInput(this.value)" >
                                    <option selected="selected" value="">Search Vehicles By</option>
                                    <option value="1">VIN</option>
                                    <option value="2">Registration Number</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li class="inputselectvin"><input type="text" placeholder="Search by VIN" class="defaultinput full searchbyvin"/></li>
                        <li class="inputselectreg"><input type="text" placeholder="Search by Registration" class="defaultinput full searchbyreg"/></li>
                        <li class="viewvehicle">
                        <button onclick="capturePhoto(); return false;" class="btnRed fleft" >TAKE A PICTURE</button>
                        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />


                        </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                    <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                    <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                </div>
                  <p id="info"></p>
        </div>
```

Below is the contents of barcoding.js

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// `load`, `deviceready`, `offline`, and `online`.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.getElementById('scan').addEventListener('click', this.scan, false);
    document.getElementById('encode').addEventListener('click', this.encode, false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of `this` is the event. In order to call the `receivedEvent`
// function, we must explicity call `app.receivedEvent(...);`
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},

// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
},

scan: function() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
   );       
},
};
```

Any idea on whats wrong? Been working on this for hours and getting no where

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to remove this comma ?

```
   scan: function() {
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
              alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
          }, 
          function (error) {
              alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          }
       );       
    }, <---------------------------- This comma
    };
```